# Django select a random image

Tags: python, django, directory

I'm trying to select a random image from a given directory.

I have found [Random_Image](https://github.com/toshism/django-random-image) on GitHub and I'm trying to use that.

Here's a snippet of the instructions:
[Snippet of Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uImVr.png)

I'm relatively new to Django so this might seem like a silly question, but what am I doing wrong here?

---

When I run the code below I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/app_pickfeel/images/9.jpg'
```

---

**Random_Image.py**

```
import os
import random
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
# module-level variable
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def random_image(image_dir):
try:
valid_extensions = settings.RANDOM_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS
except AttributeError:
valid_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', ]
if image_dir:
rel_dir = image_dir
else:
rel_dir = settings.RANDOM_IMAGE_DIR
rand_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, rel_dir)
files = [f for f in os.listdir(rand_dir) if os.path.splitext(f)[1]
in valid_extensions]
return os.path.join(rel_dir, random.choice(files))
```

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

# template tags
'app_pickfeel.templatetags.random_Image'
]


MEDIA_ROOT = 'app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/'
RANDOM_IMAGE_DIR = '/images/'
RANDOM_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = ['.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif']
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

**img src**

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% random_image "app_pickfeel/images/" %}">
```

**Images are located in the directory:**

```
'Pickfeel/app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/images'
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Is this a typo or is this the right directory : Pickfeel/app_pickfeel/static/aoo_pickfeel/images. You have aoo_pickfeel not app_pickfeel @Dom

Comment: Sorry, indeed that was a typo. I have updated the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you are in dev mode, did you configure urlpatterns for static files?:
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development](http://Serve%20Static%20Files%20during%20development)

Second look at the error url,It cannot find this file:
'app_pickfeel/static/**app_pickfeel/app_pickfeel**/images/9.jpg'

Then just to be sure is this a typo or not, You say images are located in this directory:
'Pickfeel/app_pickfeel/static/**aoo_pickfeel**/images'.

In other hand, there is no need you do this:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% random_image "app_pickfeel/images/" %}">
```

by doing this you are joning MEDIA_URL and "app_pickfeel/images/" so the directory will as the one shown in the error. You already have

```
RANDOM_IMAGE_DIR = '/images/'
```

If you do want to use it should be this way:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{% random_image "/images/" %}">
```

Which is the same as RANDOM_IMAGE_DIR = '/images/' or you can put another subdirectory of that folder "app_pickfeel"